# Bootstrap grid divs overlap when the browser is resized

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

Can anyone tell me why the two rows at the bottom of this page overlap when the browser is resized smaller? I've been experimenting with it for hours now and have had no luck!

Here is the site: [www.ecostructionny.com](http://www.ecostructionny.com)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `#words` `div` has the height set to a value of `122px`. Since the fluid layout is reducing the width of the row, the text is getting "squeezed" down.

The solution is to not set the height of the div, but instead include a "clearfix" `<hr>` element. This can be done by adding the following code to the `#words` `div`:

```
<hr style='border: none; clear: both'>
```

Comment: That worked great, except that the #words was basically styling the background color behind the blocks of text. Now with no height specified it just looks like a line. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Also what's odd is that as the browser is sized down, the Carousel gets smaller as it should, but then gets bigger. Seems strange.

Comment: I would just apply the background color to the parent div of `#words`. This should solve the background color issue without disrupting anything else.